# Gray Play button over the video in WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, video, webview

**Note: i tried every suggested method on SO, none of theme worked.**

when creating a WebView for a wordpress site the video poster is not showing instead i'm getting a gray play button over the player.
i just want to remove that button to let the video poster show..

here is my code:

```
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()"); }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
}
}
```